# Create Variable In Oracle

Tags: oracle, variables

What is the Oracle equivalent of this MS SQL Server notation?

```
DECLARE @Variable INT
SET @Variable = 1
```

Answer (score 4):

In PL/SQL, you have a declare block:

```
declare
    x integer := 1;
    ...
begin
    ...
end;
```

If you are writing an SQL*Plus script, you use `variable` to declare a [bind variable](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sqlplus/use_vars.html)

```
variable x integer := 1;
```

It's also possible to [define](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sqlplus/define.html) variables.

Answer (score 2):

In PL/SQL:

```
DECLARE
  a number;
BEGIN
  a := 1;
END;
```

You can paste this code in SQLPlus to run it.